# Are scanf arguments allowed to alias?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using scanf to extract very regular tabular data. I need to go over it in two passes and can safely ignore some of the arguments some of the time.
I want to allocate space for only the strings I care about and a single "discard" string for the others. If I pass this argument multiple times as output, is the behavior defined?

A silly minimal example:

```
char label[MAX_SIZE], discard[MAX_SIZE];
sscanf(input, "%s %s %s %s", discard, label, discard, discard);
```

Comment: The assignments within `scanf()` are done sequentially so there should be no problem.

Comment: Why are you not doing `sscanf(input, "%*s %s %*s %*s", label);` using the ***assignment suppression operator***?

Comment: Because I'm actually passing the arguments to a function that extracts the fields after doing some other work, I just want to ignore those fields sometimes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A reason to _not_ use `*` is to process the return value of `sscanf()` to note which part of `input` was assigned to `discard` in the case of an incomplete scan.  IOWs, how much of the scan succeeded.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I vote this as a dupe, but did not want the dupe hammer as I hoped for additional votes to agree or disagree would be needed.  Vote to re-open should you see fit.  It appears to be a dupe of the title question, but not a dupe of the post's body.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot find any language in the C11 standard that makes your intended usage invalid.

There seems to be a better solution, though. If you place a `*` (“assignment suppression character”) after the `%` in the format string, then the `scanf` function will parse but not store the input item. Hence, you don't have to (must not, actually) provide a destination argument for it. Seems to be exactly what you need here.

Comment: it is funny that something as simple as C can still have stuff hidden from me.

Comment: @GradyPlayer While I find the C programming language simple and elegant, the `scanf` function is a complex beast. So much that I avoid it if possible.

Comment: In this case I have a function that extracts it, and I want the fields some of the time. I'll probably end up doing something like you suggest and special casing it later. This one was more of a curiosity.

Comment: @5gon12eder, yeah I probably haven't ever actually used the scanf function outside of trying to repro problems people have on SO, etc... and if I am reading structured data from a file, I certainly am not using fscanf... I can plead scanf ignorance...

Answer (score 6):

> If I pass this argument multiple times as output, is the behaviour defined?

Citing C11:

> 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function

```
     int fscanf(FILE * restrict stream,
          const char * restrict format, ...);
```

> 4. The fscanf function executes each directive of the format **in turn**. When all directives have been executed, or if a directive fails (as detailed below), the function returns.

The `fscanf` function (and therefore `sscanf`) executes each directive of the format **in turn**, therefore there should be no problems assigning to `discard` parameters multiple times, as the final assignment would have the final effect (overwriting the previous assignments).